# Как исправить ошибку в программе ?(Python)

Tags: python

Помогите найти в чём проблема тут:

```
def идеальный_вес():  
    print('Введите м если вы мужчина или ж если вы женщина')
    пол=(sys.stdin.readline())
    print('Введите ваш рост')
    рост=int(sys.stdin.readline())

    if (пол=='м'):
        вес=(((рост*4/2.54)-128)*0.453)
    elif (пол=='ж'):        
        вес=(((рост*3.5/2.54)-108)**0.453)  
    print('Ваш идеальный вес:%s' %вес)
```

Пишет,что:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    идеальный_вес()

  File "<pyshell#43>", line 10, in идеальный_вес
    print('Ваш идеальный вес:%s' %вес)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'вес' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, ещё в формуле ошиблись. У вас для женского идеального веса возведение в степень есть: `**`. Думаю, Вы хотели умножить: `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная объявляется внутри блоков условного выражения, которые могут и не выполниться, поэтому за пределами условного выражения этой переменной не существует.

**UPD:**

```
вес = 'неизвестен'
if пол == 'м':
    вес = (((рост * 4 / 2.54) - 128) * 0.453)
elif пол == 'ж':
    вес = (((рост * 3.5 / 2.54) - 108) ** 0.453)
```

или

```
if пол == 'м':
    вес = (((рост * 4 / 2.54) - 128) * 0.453)
elif пол == 'ж':
    вес = (((рост * 3.5 / 2.54) - 108) ** 0.453)
else:
    вес = 'неизвестен'
```

Хотя правильнее, если введено неожиданное значение, выбрасывать исключение, как в других двух ответах.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Очевидно, объявить переменную за пределами условного выражения или в блоке `else`.

Comment: А вы можете, если не сложно это продемонстрировать?

Comment: @ВладАпухтин дополнил ответ.

Comment: В этом случае в итоге он будет всегда печатать:Ваш идеальный вес:неизвестно

Comment: @ВладАпухтин нет, только если в переменной `пол` будет не буква 'м' или 'ж'.

Comment: Вот и я так подумал, но даже если я пишу "м", он пишет, что : Ваш идеальный вес:неизвестно. С "ж"аналогично

Comment: @ВладАпухтин https://ideone.com/X2M9Yv

Answer (score 2):

Я бы реализовал это так:

```py
def get_ideal_weight(gender: str, height: int) -> int:
    if gender == 'м':
        weight = ((height * 4 / 2.54) - 128) * 0.453
    elif gender == 'ж':
        weight = ((height * 3.5 / 2.54) - 108) * 0.453
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Value '{gender}' is not one of: 'м', 'ж'")

    return weight


def main() -> None:
    gender = input('Введите "м", если вы мужчина или "ж", если вы женщина: ')
    height = int(input('Введите ваш рост: '))

    ideal_weight = get_ideal_weight(gender, height)
    print(ideal_weight)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `assert gender in ('м', 'ж')` - не будет исполняться без флага отладки интерпретатора Python. Т.е. во время "реальной эксплуатации" эта проверка будет проигнорирована. Но, в данном случае, проверка должна выполняться при использовании "в продакшене". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097706/why-assert-is-not-largely-used

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Действительно, спасибо за замечание. Не знал этого. А как в таком случае стоит поступить? Выбрасывать исключение, как в Вашем примере?

Comment: Да, использовать `if` и `raise`. `assert` - проверка кода **только** "времени разработки". Т.е. проверяем свой код, а не пользовательский ввод. Основное назначение `assert` - проверить, что функция получила переменную нужного типа, например.

Comment: Еще дополнение: `if нормальное поведение elif нормальное поведение else ошибка` ;)

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Действительно, спасибо :) Функция же чаще будет работать правильно, туплю сегодня.

Comment: Это пятница. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (пол=='м'):
    вес=(((рост*4/2.54)-128)*0.453)
elif (пол=='ж'):        
    вес=(((рост*3.5/2.54)-108)**0.453)
else:
    raise ValueError(f"пол={пол} должен содержать 'м' или 'ж'")
print('Ваш идеальный вес:%s' %вес)
```